# TextBox will not be updated periodically

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have created a simple .net core wpf application to represent my problem. On the MainWindow there is a TextBox, which should be updated periodically via Binding. But the TextBox only shows 'Hello world' but not the time.

Thanks for any hints!

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DebugText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,191,10,192"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly ViewModel _viewModel = new ViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = _viewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfTest
{
    public class ViewModel : UserControl
    {
        private Timer _updateTimer;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            DebugText = "Hello world";

            AutoResetEvent timerEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);
            _updateTimer = new Timer(OnTimer, timerEvent, 1000, 1000);
        }

        private void OnTimer(object stateInfo)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                DebugText = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            });
        }

        public string DebugText
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(DebugTextProperty);
            set => SetValue(DebugTextProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DebugTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DebugText",
                                        typeof(string),
                                        typeof(MainWindow),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Better use a DispatcherTimer. Its Tick event is fired in the UI thread, so that you would not have to use the Dispatcher.

Comment: `public class ViewModel : UserControl` looks odd. A view model should not be derived from a view class.

Comment: Did you debug your program to see whether the line `DebugText = DateTime.Now.ToString();` is ever executed?

Comment: And: `typeof(MainWindow)` in DependencyProperty.Register is wrong. It must be `typeof(ViewModel)`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

I changed the Timer to DispatcherTimer and removed the part with Dispatcher.Invoke. The main problem was the wrong type. I changed typeof(MainWindow) to typeof(ViewModel) and now it works!

Just one question: if ViewModel should not derive from UserControl, how do I have to realize the property (GetValue and SetValue)?

Comment: The ViewModel class would implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. You don't need a dependency property. For completeness, a class that would need to expose dependency properties, but would not be a view class (which is rather rare) would derive from DependencyObject.